# swi-prolog wait_for_input on files where the stream is at the end of the file

Tags: input, wait, swi-prolog

I don't understand why wait_for_input is not waiting when the end of a file is reached. I tried it on Mac OS X with swi-prolog 7.6.0 and Red Hat linux 6, with swi-prolog 5.7.11. I open a stream to a file that contains the single line "f(1).", without the quotes. I get the following behavior, where wait_for_input returns but reading the stream gives end_of_file.

?- open('file.prolog',read,InStrm,[alias(instrm),eof_action(reset)]).
InStrm = instrm.

?- wait_for_input([instrm],RL,15).
RL = [instrm].

?- read(instrm,Trm).
Trm = f(1).

?- wait_for_input([instrm],RL,15).
RL = [instrm].

?- read(instrm,Trm).
Trm = end_of_file.

I use eof_action(reset) so that if another process appends to the file, the reader will get the new data.

Answer (score 0):

wait_for_input/3 is not really supposed to be used for your use case.

According to Swi-Prolog's documentation, wait_for_input/3 by default uses "poll" system call (when available, which should be true in your case):

> When available, the implementation is based on the poll() system call.

"poll" system call, in turn, always succeeds immediately for regular files:

> Regular files shall always poll TRUE for reading and writing.

See following links for further information:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=wait_for_input/3

https://linux.die.net/man/3/poll